# Remove a key:value from json string stored in a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-json

I have a column in table which is stored in format:

```
{"field1":"val1","field2":"val4"}
{"field1":"val2","field2":"val5"}
{"field1":"val3","field2":"val6"}
```

I need to remove all field1 with values(e.g "field1":"val1","field1":"val2","field1":"val3" ) and result should be

```
{"field2":"val4"}
{"field2":"val5"}
{"field2":"val6"}
```

I am trying to acheive this via replace but stuck as in '"field1":"val1"' string val1 could be any value like null, some integer.

```
UPDATE emp SET col = REPLACE(col, '"field1":"val1"', '')
```

I am stuck due to this dynamic value of val1.

Comment: You would need to use regular expressions to achieve this. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql). However, some people seem to have found a workaround.

Comment: If you are using php, you can iterate each row and use the code below to get that particular row without field1

$str='{"field1":"val1","field2":"val4"}';
        $array  = json_decode($str);
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            if($key=="field1") continue;
            else echo "$key:$value<br>";
        }

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I would prefer to use the JSON_REMOVE function (MySQL) :

```
UPDATE emp
SET emp.col = JSON_REMOVE(emp.col, '$.field1');
```

You can also add a WHERE clause :

```
WHERE emp.col LIKE '%val6%';
```

*References:* [MySQL JSON_REMOVE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-remove) and [MySQL JSON path](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-path-syntax.html)

*A blog post with examples:* [MySQL for your JSON](https://www.compose.com/articles/mysql-for-your-json/)

*And a note about json path in MySQL:*

> Propery names in path must be double quoted if the property identifier contains interpunction (spaces, special characters, meta characters) [bugs.mysql.com](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79051)

Answer (score -3):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Field, 1, INSTR(Field, '"field1"')) + SUBSTRING(Field, INSTR(Field, '"field2"'), LENGTH(Field)) FROM @Temp
```

I don't know if this works but this is the idea. (Can't test ATM)

Here is the MsSQL equivalent (works, just tested!):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Field, 0, CHARINDEX('"field1"', Field)) + SUBSTRING(Field, CHARINDEX('"field2"', Field), LEN(Field)) FROM @Temp
```